# Laravel - How to display WYSIWYG and also truncate the string

Tags: laravel, wysiwyg, truncate

I am using Laravel-5.8 for a web application project.

In the Project, I used text editor for a particular field called **goal_description** and the datatype is longtext.

```
public function index()
{
  $goals = Goal::all();
  return view('goals.index')->with('goals', $goals);
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  @foreach($goals as $key => $goal)
    <td>
       {{$key+1}}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{$goal->goal_title ?? '' }}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{$goal->goal_description ?? '' }}
    </td>
  @endforeach 
</tbody>
```

I have two issues:

1. How do I display goal_description without the HTML tags, but it will format the field
2. How do I truncate the field to the length of 20 with ellpse ..., then when the ellipse is clicked, it will display everything.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by ellipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1> use 
`{!!$goal->goal_description ?? '' !!}`

Issue 2> I really dont know what ellipse is. But to truncate a string just use str as below

```
{!! Str::limit($goal->goal_description, 20, ' ...') !!}
```

Comment: ellipsis is the ... that you added. But how do I do it that when I click on the ..., it will display the whole text again.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>{{str_limit(html_entity_decode($goal->goal_description),300)}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To support @Deepesh Thapa answer you can do this?

```
{!! Str::limit($goal->goal_description, 20) !!}<a href="#"> ...</a>
```

Or you can use any other element and use Ajax to toggle it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).